# Java - Adding Elements to Array of Hashmaps Produces Null Error

Tags: java, arrays, generics, hashmap

I am trying to create a 2d array of hashmaps. I do this with the following code:

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Boolean>[][] arrayBlock3 = (Map <String, Boolean>[][]) new Map[6][6];
```

When I try to add elements to the array however, at runtime there is a null pointer exception at the first line adding an element to the array.

The code to add an element is:

```
    arrayBlock3[0][0].put("B", false);
    arrayBlock3[0][1].put("G", false);
    arrayBlock3[0][2].put("B", false);
    arrayBlock3[0][3].put("B", false);
    arrayBlock3[0][4].put("G", false);
    arrayBlock3[0][5].put("B", false);
```

Error Message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at main.main(main.java:20)
```

I would really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: What is `Map`?..

Comment: Hint: what do you believe the value of `arrayBlock3[0][0]` is, and why?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am trying to assign a value to `arrayBlock3[0][0]` and in doing that a null pointer exception is thrown but I am unsure as to why.

Comment: Nope, you're not trying to assign a value to that array element. You're *fetching* the value of that array element and calling a method on it. The value of the array element is null.

Comment: A good rule of thumb when working with arrays is that something has to allocate the array (Usually something like new a[4]) and something has to allocate each element in the array (like new ArrayList()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize each element in that matrix of `Map` (and you need to use a class that implements `Map`, such as `HashMap`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayBlock3.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayBlock3[i].length; j++) {
        arrayBlock3[i][j] = new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @YCF_L! For some reason, had forgotten those haha